Delay allocating AVAudioPlayer with URL of sound in iOS simulator iOS 17.2
Has anyone experienced a delay while allocating and initializing an instance of AVAudioPlayer with the URL of a sound? The delay is barely noticeable (~1.5 seconds) using the iOS 17.2 simulator but is really affecting game play of my app:
- (void)playAudio:(NSString *)resource
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:resource ofType:@"m4a"]];
    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url fileTypeHint:@"m4a" error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else
    {
        [audioPlayer play];
    }
} 

I am already preparing audio during app launch, so that is not the problem:
- (void)prepareAudio:(NSString *)audioPath
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:audioPath ofType:@"m4a"]];
    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url fileTypeHint:@"m4a" error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else
    {
        audioPlayer.delegate = self;
        [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    }
}

This error does not happen with the iOS 16.4 simulator.
